# How build Query String

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to build query strings for the following questions -

1. Display records where the batch codes are on Sun and from Jamnagar City and Reliance only.
2. Display records where the batch codes are on Sun and from Jamnagar City, Reliance and TATA only.

My weekly Access table -

```
batch_code    bday             duration          period_no          branch
B001          Sun                   1            2                  Jamnagar City
B001          Mon                   1            2                  Jamnagar City
B001          Tue                   1            2                  Jamnagar City
B002          Mon                 1.3            4                  TATA
B002          Mon                 1.3            4                  TATA
B003          Sun                   1            1                  Jamnagar City
B003          Mon                   1            1                  Jamnagar City
B004          Sun                   2            2                  Reliance
B004          Mon                   2            2                  Reliance
B004          Tue                   2            2                  Reliance
B005          Sun                   2            2                  TATA
B005          Mon                   2            2                  TATA
B005          Tue                   2            2                  TATA
B006          Sun                 1.3            4                  Jamnagar City
B007          Wed                 1.3            4                  Jamnagar City
```

Comment: And what have you tired ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE bday='Sun' AND (branch='Jamnagar City' OR branch='Reliance')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE bday='Sun' AND (branch='Jamnagar City' OR branch='Reliance')
2. SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE bday='Sun' AND (branch='Jamnagar City' OR branch='Reliance' OR branch='TATA')

I believe you can use the IN command, but I'm not positive if it works in Access.  You can try it though.  Syntax would be:

SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE bday='Sun' AND branch IN ('Jamnagar City', 'Reliance', 'TATA')

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Yes IN works with Access and I used that only.